# Why can I debug only once in Intellij with JBOSS?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jboss

I'm trying to debug a server ran with JBOSS 7.1 in IntelliJ. It works fine the first time and stops in every breakpoint properly. However, if I try to do the same a second time without stopping the server, then it works as expected but it does not stop in any breakpoint.

I think it could be related to my standalone:

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
else
   echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
```

Any idea on what should I do or look for?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Has your code changed on the second debug?

Comment: No, it has not changed. It even has the same behavior.